# local tiles server for offline access

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2, tiles, cache, tilecache

Anyone knows if there is a "lightway" solution to mount a local tile server?

Feature I'd to provide is local storage of small sections of maps, not more than small city for example, in order to provide some degree of offline maps navigation by pointing javascript functions to the local server when network is not accessible.

Comment: Maps on a Stick? http://developmentseed.org/blog/2010/mar/11/offline-mapping-visualizations-maps-stick/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org), you could utilise the OpenLayers plugin. Progams such as [Mapertive](http://maperitive.net/) can download tiles from OpenStreetMap, using the generate-tiles method. Other programs may be available for other sources. Mapertive exports the images into the 'Tiles' subfolder.

Once you have the tiles downloaded, make a copy of one of the files in the qgis\python\plugins\openlayers_plugin\html folder, except modify the statement which creates a layer.

In this example I am using MS Windows, and OpenStreetMap. I would replace

```
   var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
          "OpenStreetMap",
          "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
```

with:

```
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
              "OpenStreetMap",
              "C:/Path-to/Maperitive-latest/Maperitive/Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
```

I saved this file as qgis\python\plugins\openlayers_plugin\html\osm_local.html

Last thing to do is modify the openlayers_plugin.py file, by registering the new html file.

```
# Layers
self.olLayerTypeRegistry = OlLayerTypeRegistry()

# Add this
self.olLayerTypeRegistry.add( OlLayerType(self, 'OpenStreetMap (Cache)', 'osm_icon.png', 'osm_local.html', True) )
```

After restarting QGIS, you will have a new option in the OpenLayers menu

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also set up a local tile server using [TileLite](https://bitbucket.org/springmeyer/tilelite/wiki/Home). It's a lightweight Python tile-server using Mapnik rendering and designed to serve tiles in the OSM (OpenStreetMap) scheme.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know whether it is what you want or not but OpenLayers has Offline Storage for calling tiles from browser local storage. There is an example [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/offline-storage.html)

Comment: The link is broken